# Firewall: name with changing IP

Tags: android, firewall, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working with a firewall not administrated by me. I asked the admin to let the firewall accept all messages directed to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send. That is, messages to https://android.googleapis.com with port 443.

As soon as he applied the rule it started working, but the next day it didn't. I told the admin, he accepted all ports (not just 443) and then it started working, but today's not working again. The IP of https://android.googleapis.com changes (today's IP is 173.194.66.95, several days ago it was 173.194.78.95), and I guess the firewall only does the name resolution once (or at least just a few times), so when the IP changes the communication is filtered. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incredibly likely that android.googleapis.com is a number of IPs. unless you have a cheap firewall like zone alarm which can do it by name, you would normally need to have the rule for all the IPs that the and accept also google can change them at any time and wont necessarily notify anyone.